# vim search-replace question

Tags: regex, vim

I have a few trace lines in my file of the form

```
M_TRACE(EV_TRACE_LEVEL_DEBUG, "some trace");
```

I want to convert those into

```
M_TRACE(EV_TRACE_LEVEL_DEBUG, "%s: some trace", __FUNCTION__);
```

However I have already a few traces which display the function name also.

To make the conversion i am using the following command

```
:%g/M_TRACE/s/"\(.*\)"/"%s: \1", __FUNCTION__/c
```

which unfortunately includes a redundant **FUNCTION** in some places.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Hello arun kumar, welcome to stack overflow!  Please mark an answer as accepted if you found a solution that worked for you.  This community grows when we all participate. Not marking answers accepted will damage your reputation and discourage future eager volunteers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a single command:

```
:%g/M_TRACE/s/"\(.*\)"\(, __FUNCTION__\)\?/"%s: \1", __FUNCTION__/
```

It will replace the ", `__FUNCTION__`" if its already present or it simply append it if its not present.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
   :%g/M_TRACE.*\");/s/"\(.*\)"/"%s: \1", __FUNCTION__/c
```

to exclude lines with an arg after the string.

2nd try:
Use Vim's zero-width negative look-behind pattern:

```
%g/M_TRACE.*\(__FUNCTION__\)\@<!);/s/"\(.*\)"/"%s: \1", __FUNCTION__/
```

That's `M_TRACE` followed by a **);** thats NOT preceded by `__FUNCTION__`

Comment: Unfortunately I had many macros with arguments also. Am sorry not to have mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in two steps: first replace the part inside the quotes, then replace `")` with `", __FUNCTION__)`

However, if you just want to do it with just one command:

```
:%g/M_TRACE/s/"\(.*\)".*/"%s: \1", __FUNCTION__);
```

Comment: My substitution will did both. It is just that I was not able to select only those lines without __FUNCITON__. Instead of doing it in two steps as u have suggested I used the confirm flag(/c).

I want to know if there is an even better way to do that

Comment: Well doing two substitutions removes the need for the manual confirmation, sounds like a better way to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a *few* (dozen) you can just do an interactive search/replace using `i`nteractive mode:

```
:%g/M_TRACE/s/"\(.*\)"/"%s: \1", __FUNCTION__/igc
```

and just step through them. Answering y/n as you go.